# Какая технология самая быстрая для web-программирования?

Tags: node.js, python, java, hotspot

Вопрос ребром, какая технология или язык самый
быстрый на сегодняшний день для web разработки?
Смотря для каких задач?
Да для всех задач, понятно, что не для информационной html
странички.

Comment: Вам нужна быстрая разработка или быстрая система?

Comment: Читайте про серверные модули по ключевым словам ISAPI, NSAPI.

Comment: Написано же - быстрый ... для веб-разработки

Comment: Скорость разработки зависит от разработчика и от разрабатываемого объекта. Везде есть уже готовы библиотеки и фреймворки ускоряющие разработку(в пайтон много библиотек из коробки, их не нужно ставить, что может сэкономить вам время), опишите задачу, можно будет сказать более точно что подойдет.

Comment: Почитал комментарии. Надо отталкиваться от противного - НЕ пишите на ассемблере, а то веб-разработка точно очень затянется)

Comment: Вот странно, почему этот вопрос до сих пор не закрыт с пометкой "слишком спорно". Ведь гораздо менее холиварные вопросы закрывают.

Comment: @northerner, видимо ник у ТС магический, рука не поднимается.

Answer (score 11):

Я скажу Python, другие скажут PHP, потом придут RoR фанаты, и ответа Вы не получите. Т.к. однозначного ответа нет, например:

> - Вконтакте, facebook - это **PHP**
> - yandex, google - это **python**
> - githab - это **рельсы**

***Каждый этот проект - это медиа-гигант,
 так что что лучше нельзя сказать.***

и это только то что я вспомнил...например найти специалиста PHP будет легче и дешевле, чем того же python.

---

Единственное что скажу про PHP: это **P**ersonal **H**ome **P**age, личная страничка не более того, да веб-страницы на нем писать легко, но большие приложения ТОЖЕ МОЖНО, но это будет туго...

На это есть не сколько причин, основная это недоООП, да и вообще многие вещи нужно будет реализовывать самому, а ценится пых своей простотой :)

Comment: Ммм, а я думал что PHP - это рекурсивный акроним от PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor нынче

Comment: Да, Personal Home Page он был только до третьей версии.

> большие приложения ТОЖЕ МОЖНО, но это будет туго...

А мужики-то (Цукерберг, Дуров, Уэйлс) не знают :)

> основная это недоООП, да и вообще многие вещи нужно будет реализовывать самому

Фреймворки решают.

Ответ плюсую - однозначного ответа действительно нет. В 99.999% случаев хорошо написанный код с использованием одного инструмента не будет уступать хорошо написанному коду с использованием другого. И скорость разработки, если посадить двух профи, тоже будет сравнимой (хотя бы потому, что в профессиональной разработке кодинга мало).

Comment: Вы смеетесь вконтакте php, ну-ну) там от пхп уже ничего наверно практически и не осталось то (ага и скайп написан на дельфи)

Comment: PHP с версии 5 и выше такое же ООП язык, как и другие. Personal Home Page - версия PHP 1, 2FI, 3. Теперь PHP это PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor.

Comment: о да, сделали рекурсивный акроним +10 к клёвости языка

Comment: Плюсую антипохапешные высказывания.

Comment: > А мужики-то (Цукерберг, Дуров, Уэйлс) не знают :)

Разработать транслятор из `PHP` в `C++` на `C` и при этом переписать половину расширений, только ради того, что бы достичь приемлемой скорости работы и масштабируемости одного единственного сайта... По моему, это как раз и называется:

> ТОЖЕ МОЖНО, но это будет туго...

Comment: google - это python? :D

Слава богу не PHP :D

Comment: Когда создавались википедия и фейсбук, рельсов еще не было. Питон вроде как существовал, но не знаю, насколько он годился для веб-разработки

Comment: Та ладно?
     
      Вконтакте, facebook - это PHP

С чего это вы взяли? По большому счету во всех( в 90% точно ) веб проектах используется PHP. В одних больше, в других меньше. Вконтакте и питон используется и рельсы, и C++ и еще много чего.

Comment: >Вконтакте и питон используется и рельсы

[ВКонтакте: как устроена социальная сеть](http://www.xakep.ru/post/55052/), какие питон и рельсы?

Answer (score 6):

Вставлю свои пять копеек.

- stackoverflow.com - С#
- linkedin.com - Java

Про PHP, RoR, Python уже говорили. На любом языке разработка быстрее, если пишут прямые руки и светлые головы. Светлые головы быстрее напишут на питоне или рельсах, чем на джаве, факт. Но так как светлых голов всегда не хватает, берут более строгую джаву/шарп и пишут на них. Ошибки в статически типизированом языке искать гораздо проще, чем в динамическом. Написать код каждый может, а вот привести его в нормальный вид после QA гораздо сложнее. 
Где-то на Хабре видел статью, как человек хвалил питон. И проблему с минусами динамических языков он решил очень просто - TDD. Но до TDD обычно проходится большой путь -> просветление головы.

Answer (score 4):

Готовая цмска

Comment: а по-моему, максимум быстродействия можно добиться только "руками"

Comment: быстродействия чего? на велосипеде можно быстро ехать...

Comment: нет универсальной CMS заточеной под абсолютно любые задачи

Comment: Зачем универсальная? Надо бери для магазина, для блога, сайта, портфолио и т.  д.  Сразу же видно было, что вопрос провакационный, скорость зависит от кол-ва разработчиков, их квалификации, железа, самой задачи - в итоге от бабла, которое у тебя есть на разработку.

Comment: > а по-моему, максимум быстродействия можно добиться только "руками"

Речь же о скорости разработки, а не работы.

Answer (score 4):

На мой взгляд, самыми быстрыми для разработки являются Руби и Питон.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд , самая удобная для веб-программирования - это [ASP.NET](http://ASP.NET) MVC. На Java я не программировал, поэтому он может быть не хуже. Но чем [ASP.NET](http://ASP.NET) хороший, то это поддержкой пользователей, удобной документацией и постоянным обновлением программных средств. Хочу сказать, что php удобно только в том случае, когда ты никогда не программировал и тебе трудно разобраться с вещами типа JAVA или .NET. PHP стоит выучить любому разработчику, но зацикливаться на нем не стоит, так как там приходиться писать руками много неинтересного кода.

Comment: вы будете очень удивлены, когда поищите сколько всего уже написано на php. А документации и примеров наверняка не меньше, чем в ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Ну или на Джангу посмотрите. Для Пайтона все еще радужней

Comment: Я не буду удивлен, так как просидел на PHP больше года. Относительно документации. Документации к самому языку море, но вот ко множеству фреймворкам, только на Английском или и без этого. Да и Фреймворки написанные на PHP имеют поддержку не из сотни программистов, как на .NET, а из нескольких энтузиастов. Поэтому, изучая очередной фреймворк на PHP, вы рискуете одного дня остаться на окончательно устаревшем фреймворке, без обновлений и пользователей. Я кончено никого не агитирую, но PHP это очень низко-профессиональное сообщество, и множество программистов кочуют с него в поисках легкой жизни.

Comment: Возможно Пайтон, Джава, или Руби тоже хорошие средства, но пока меня устраивает ASP.NET.

Comment: Думаю вы сильно удивитесь какой комьюнити у действительно крупных PHP фрэйворков, навскидку Symfony или Zend, явно даже не сотня программистов. Не сильно хочу защищать PHP, но в чем тут явно не откажешь так в группе сторонников
PS Плакаться о том что документация не на твоем языке в программировании IMHO моветон, естественно, если это не разработки русских программеров, к тому же допустим в Zend Framework документация переведена на русский процентов на 90.

Comment: Программировать на .NET - это лично мой выбор. Меня не волнует, что скажут незнакомые мне люди по этому поводу. Я сказал, что именно меня заставило перейти на .NET и автор вопроса может учесть или нет мое мнение, остальное меня не волнует.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, что бы дать конкретный ответ на данный вопрос нужно разработать проект с одинаковым функционалом к примеру на следующих языках:

- Perl
- PHP
- Ruby
- С#

И дать оценку затраченного времени! Не писать говнокод, а именно OOP!

Найдуться такие которые ответят по факту на чем плясать быстрее?

Comment: Не писать говнокод, а именно ООП. ООП не может быть говнокодом? А почему ООП, а не функциональщину, например?

Comment: кстати хороший вопрос. А то сейчас много разговор про функциональные языки, и столько же разговоров, что ООП себя не оправдал. Где правду искать?

Comment: Истина, как всегда, где-то посредине

Comment: хоть ооп работает медленее (в чем оно могло себя не оправдать) чем обычные функции, но работать с объектами проще... это чисто имхо...

--------------------

З.Ы. и на ООП пишут говнокод, не отрицаю!

Comment: никто не выделит ни времени ни денег написать один и тот же проект на разных ЯП. Плюс когда одна команда напишет проект на одном ЯП, на следующем ЯП писать ГОРАЗДО легче такой же проект. А у разных команд может сильно различаться продуктивность. Другими словами, объективно оценить не удасться

Comment: Ну, допустим, писать можно и just for fun. Не хлебом же единым... Тут вопрос не в языке как таковом, а в доступных либах, пакетах, фреймворках. Как писал товарищ МакКоннелл, писать нужно не на языке, *а с использованием языка*.

Comment: а на счет неопрвдания ожиданий - говорили про повторное использование кода. Все мечтали, что можно будет бизнес логику раз написать и забыть. Что-то вроде для банка написать раз систему, и во все банки пихать - не вышло. А вот с логированием, командной строкой и прочей мелочью - очень даже вышло)

Answer (score 0):

Пишите: сервер - Python (фреймвёрк Web2py), клиент - HTML+IronPython+Silverlight. Можно "чёрта лысого" сделать, и быстро и эффективно, но спецов мало ;-)) (и там и там)))).